# What does one study to increase understanding of the $P \stackrel{?}{=} NP$ problem?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

If one were to learn more about the $P \stackrel{?}{=} NP$ problem, where would one start?

I understand what the problem is—but not enough to be able to read anything technical about it. Furthermore, I don't know where to start. When reading "This problem can be solved in $n^k$ steps" I only have a vague clue about how one goes about rigorously proving a statement like that.

Would getting an introductory book in something like boolean algebra be of use? Or should one focus more directly on computational complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a book on theoretical computer science, which will cover at least formal languages/automata, computability, and complexity. Sipser's "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" is widely used and a good place to start. From there you can start picking up auxiliary resources depending on what you have a hard time understanding.

A MOOC course might also be helpful.
Here's UDacity's [Intro to Theoretical Computer Science](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs313)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a classical book: Hopcroft J.and others *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation*. You can star from the chapter about Turing machines and go further. And [here](http://www.aduni.org/courses/theory/index.php?view=cw) there is a video-lectures on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

There are several books on [Computational Complexity](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=computational+complexity+&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Acomputational+complexity+); I like the one by Papadimitriou.

The subject belongs more to Theoretical Computer Science than Mathematics, so you may find useful to ask at cstheory.stackexchange.com or take a look at book recommendations for corresponding computer science classes in various universities: many of the have class requirements in online schedules.